# Calling 3rd party api on creating new order in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce, hook

I have an e-commerce site running on WordPress, I have added functionality in which whenever a user checkout, the API of my courier is hit and a tracking code is saved in the database.
Now I want to create a custom order from the backend (Add new order in Woocommerce) and do the same thing, like calling the API and saving the tracking returned from the API call to the database, but don't know which hook to use.

Comment: you can work with: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/webhooks/

Comment: don't want to use webhook as i don't know much about using webhooks... i have used woocommerce_thankyou in function, so i want to use something similar to it when creating a new order from admin area

Answer (score 0):

you should use 'woocommerce_new_order' hook:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'api_call',  1, 1  );
function api_call( $order_id ) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();
    // etc...
}
```

[fires after new order created](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT.html#78)

Comment: will this work only for the backend? or it will also fire after frontend checkout?

Comment: it works after new order created,both front end and back end.  $order->get_created_via might be helpful to determine if its backend or frontend. dump $order and check i haven't test it my self.